# How to find the inverse of a polynomial modulo another polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra

how would you find the inverse of 2x+1
for modulus x^2+x+2?
I did euclidean division, but I'm still rather confused
x^2+x+2=(2x+1(2x)+(2x+2),

2x+2=4(5x)+2

5x=2(4x)

all in F3
I know I'm wrong but I'm very confused on this topic

Comment: You need the *extended* Euclidean algorithm. The version that lets you write the gcd as a linear combination of the two polynomials. Recall Bezout's identity from congruences. Presumable the gcd should be equal to one, for otherwise the said inverse does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Using the extended Euclidean algorithm, if $2x+1$ and $x^2+x+2$ are coprime, we can obtain $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that

$$(2x+1)f(x) + (x^2+x+2)g(x) = 1.$$

Now, with a little shifting, and we get 
$$(2x+1)f(x) = 1 - (x^2+x+2)g(x).$$
Now, take modulo $(x^2+x+2)$, we have...